# How can snippet forms be customized?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-snippet

[This part](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#wagtail.admin.forms.WagtailAdminPageForm) of the wagtail documentation shows how to customize the form of `Page` models by subclassing `WagtailAdminPageForm` and pass the subclass as `base_form_class` to the `Page` model.

It also says:

> Custom forms for snippets must subclass WagtailAdminModelForm, and custom forms for pages must subclass WagtailAdminPageForm.

However when I try the same using a snippet I get the following error:

```
ModelForm has no model class specified.
```

My code:

```
class ScheduleAdminForm(WagtailAdminModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Constructor of ScheduleAdminForm")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class Schedule(ClusterableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    base_form_class = ScheduleAdminForm
```

I also tried to add the model in the `Meta` class of the `ScheduleAdminForm`. However then I have a circular use and I can't use the model name in quotes for `Meta.model` as can be done for model fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the model's `base_form_class` attribute outside the main class definition:

```py
class Schedule(ClusterableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)


class ScheduleAdminForm(WagtailAdminModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Constructor of ScheduleAdminForm")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = ["name"]


Schedule.base_form_class = ScheduleAdminForm
```

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to declare as you've done, I do this myself:

```
    from core.forms.restricted_panels_admin_forms import \
        RestrictedPanelsAdminModelForm
    
    @register_snippet
    class StoreDepartment(ClusterableModel):
        base_form_class = RestrictedPanelsAdminModelForm
        ....
```

`RestrictedPanelsAdminModelForm` subclasses `WagtailAdminModelForm`

Only difference I can see is that it's importing the form, can't imagine that's the cause though.